# Magento Module IndexController - IndexAction function 404's

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento, module, controller

Removing the Class around the IndexAction causes a server error, so I know the code is running as expected up to that point.

```
class Foo_Bar_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "<h1>Echo from indexcontroller.</h1>";
    }
}
```

Ideally the echo would be replaced by loading template files, but I've been stuck on it 404ing for the last 2 days and just want to get past that.

I've read through about a dozen tutorial, followed 4 to completetion, but this issue pops up every time.
Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Edit--
Sorry, for the brevity. I wasn't sure how much I should distend the page.

@ Alan Storm -- I found your tutorial here. http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world (Great Detail, very helpful in understanding what all the xml tags do). This is a copy of that tutorial with Foo replacing Alanstormdotcom and Bar replacing Helloworld. Even copy/pasting I end up with the same 404.

Here is my current config file:
PATH: app/code/local/Foo/Bar/etc/config.xml (edit: corrected path)

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Foo_Bar>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Foo_Bar>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <bar>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Foo_Bar</module>
                <frontName>bar</frontName>
            </args>
        </bar>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
</config>
```

Edit---
the last remaining file
Path: app/etc/modules/Foo_Bar.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Foo_Bar>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Foo_Bar>
</modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post the relative path to your magento installation of the Bar module and the module's config.xml file?

Comment: If you've read the tutorials and think someone can answer your question with this little information, you haven't read the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is incorrect:

```
app/etc/modules/Foo/Bar/etc/config.xml
```

You should place your module's definition file `Foo_Bar.xml` in `app/etc/modules` and the code of your module in app/code/local:

```
app/code/local/Foo/Bar/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Foo/Bar/controllers/IndexController.php
```

EDIT: in order to access your controller you should access this url:

```
www.example.com/magento-instance/bar/index
```

Following this pattern:

{magento_root}/{magento_module}/{magento_controller}/{magento_action}

Comment: sorry. it is in the path you listed. I just copied the wrong one.

Comment: which URL/URI are you using to access the controller?

Comment: example.com/magento-instance/bar

Comment: The index of the action is applied by default. But "index" in that case is the controller name.

Comment: To my knowledge, index should be applied by default 
eg. www.yourdomain.com/magento-instance/bar/index == www.yourdomain.com/magento-instance/bar

I've tried both but I get the 404 either way.

Comment: Adding a new action method also 404's
added to controller:

    public function testAction() {  echo 'test'; }

attempted to access at: www.yourdomain.com/magento-instance/bar/index/test

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my local Magento installation. Can you paste also your Foo_Bar.xml file in your /etc/modules/?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I never did find out why it wouldn't work. It ended up functioning as expected on other instances of Magento.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing to add store_code in URL ( I had the same issue ), probably you have enabled the store code from admin in other words the store code (Ex: en, nl, etc) is adding in URL.

**Ex :**

> www.example.com/**en**/aaa.html

If so, then please access your controller and action in this manner:

> www.example.com/**store_code**/front_name/controller/action

**Ex :**

> www.example.com/**en**/bar/index/index

Comment: I just found out in this my mistake , thanks for your answer +1

Answer (score 0):

If other answers do not help you, you might want to try this path pattern:

```
     www.example.com/index.php/frontName/controllerName/actionName
```

I do not understand why they didn't create a rewrite rule for this kind of urls.

Anyway, the pattern above should work in most cases.